# Duplicate parent and children by python,but children are in the wrong place

Tags: python, parent

I use scripts below to duplicate and move one parent and its children. When i move parent to another location and run the scripts, parent.copy() moves from the new original location, but children.copy() move from original location. If I apply rotation & scale in parent, children move correctly.What's wrong with it? offset is a Vector(()). Thanks!

```
def duplicate(offset):
    children = []
    parent = bpy.context.object
    p = parent.copy()
    for ob in parent.children_recursive:
        a = ob.copy()
        a.matrix_world.translation = ob.matrix_world.translation + offset
        print(a.matrix_world.translation)
        children.append(a)
    p.matrix_world = Matrix.Translation(offset) @ parent.matrix_world
    print('___')
    for child in children:
        child.parent = p
        child.matrix_parent_inverse = p.matrix_world.inverted()
        print(child.matrix_world.translation)
    print('step3')
    for ob in children:
        bpy.context.collection.objects.link(ob)
        print(ob.matrix_world.translation)
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(p)
```

[image]